# Reset BIOS Password Lenovo Yoga 710-11IKB

Tags: bios, passwords

I have a Lenovo Yoga 710-11IKB that has a BIOS password that I don't ever recall setting. The computer boots up the OS just fine, but if try to get to the setup screen or boot from a USB it asks for the password. I tired "password" and "123456" for passwords, but those didn't work. Took the computer apart thinking maybe I can just remove the CMOS battery and all will be good, but there's no CMOS battery on the computer anywhere. I'd really like to use bootable media on this laptop and I'm not sure where to go from here.

EDIT:
[image]

I have pulled off the board and checked the underside as well no CMOS battery.

Comment: The CMOS battery is there, but it's not the typical battery slot that is on desktop motherboards. They usually look [like this](https://c.76.my/Malaysia/cr2032-3v-40mm-laptop-cmos-battery-01-xeustechny-1801-03-XeusTechny@4.jpg) for laptops. It's possible that it's soldered to the board, but I doubt it. Could you upload a picture of your motherboard if you still can't find it?

Comment: See my edit. I had the board off and the battery and there wasn't anything under either.

Comment: It's super hard to see in pictures. I've been looking and found only one picture that might show the CMOS. It looked like it was the bottom side, somewhere under the heatsink area.Its in [this post](https://www.ebay.com/p/Lenovo-Yoga-710-11isk-11-6-Genuine-Intel-4405y-1-5ghz-Motherboard/712456630) It's the 4th picture of the underside. All I can see is it looks silver and shiny in two spots. The only problem is it looks awfully flush to the board.

Comment: There's a lot of silver contacts on the bottom side of the board around where the heat is. I'm not about to start bridging random contacts because I don't want to short something I'm not suppose to.